# Troubles with making spring data jpa specification using native sql

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I use eclipselink as jpa provider and spring data jpa in my project. I try to construct a specification using native sql query. Code below

```
    public static Specification<AbstractDocumentPermission> userIdEqual(long userId) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.Expression expression = new ExpressionBuilder()
           .sql("SELECT ? UNION ALL SELECT ? UNION ALL SELECT ?", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

        return root.get("id").in(expression);
    };
```

Code produces `Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException`
and shows me following

```
.... WHERE (id IN (SELECT  UNION ALL SELECT ? UNION ALL SELECT ??))
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: any exception has a precise message and a stack trace.

Comment: You are right, it is syntax error on position of two question marks ('??')

Comment: And if i use other native sql with 2 selects '"SELECT ? UNION ALL SELECT ?' i caught error on invoke sql ```WHERE (id IN (SELECT  UNION ALL SELECT ??))```